# How to get the ECDSA, DER and RPB format from a RSA private key using kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have an RSA private key.  I would like to extract the public key in the following formats:

1. ECDSA
2. DER
3. RPB

I have can get the RSA formatted public from RSA formatted private key with the following code.

```
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec
import java.util.Base64
import java.security.KeyPair
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator

const val ALGORITHM = "RSA"


fun generateKeyPair(): KeyPair {
    val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048) // You can adjust the key size as needed
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
}

fun generatePublicKey(privateKeyString: String): PublicKey {
    try {
        val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)
        val encodedPrivateKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString)
        val privateKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey)
        val rsaPrivateKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec) as RSAPrivateCrtKey

        val publicKeySpec = RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey.modulus, rsaPrivateKey.publicExponent)
        return kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val keyPair = generateKeyPair()
    // val publicKey: PublicKey = keyPair.public
    val privateKey: PrivateKey = keyPair.private
    // Test with a sample private key string
    val privateKeyString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.encoded)
    println("Generated Private Key: $privateKeyString")
    //val privateKeyString = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_STRING_HERE"
    val publicKey = generatePublicKey(privateKeyString)
    println("Generated Public Key: ${Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.encoded)}")
}
```

Being that `java.security.spec` has `RSAPublicKeySpec`, i thought there would be a `ECDSAPublicKeySpec`, `DERPublicKeySpec` and `RPBPublicKeySpec`.  But, I was mistaken.  There are other format type `PublicKeySpec`'s though.

I took a look at Bouncy Castle, but was unable to get the three formats, from private key (or transform to the three formats from RSA format).

I am aware OpenSSL does everything I am asking in three commands with some flags.  I can not use OpenSSL, I need to do it in kotlin, without a OpenSSL wrapper.

I believe there are Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) and Bouncy Castle (may check again) that extend some of the functionality of cryptography in Java.  But, before I visit/re-visit, I am coming to my trusty Stackoverflow community.

### Update:

Here are the commands in OpenSSL that I am trying to recreate via Kotlin (and Java libraries).  Special emphasis on the comments in code that have **--> NEED THIS <--**

```
// Private key --> already have this
openssl genrsa -out priv.pem 2048

// Public key --> already have this
openssl rsa -in priv.pem -pubout -out pub.pem

// Public key PEM --> already have this
openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubin -in pub.pem -text -noout

// Public key DER format --> NEED THIS <--
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in pub.pem -outform DER -out pub.der

// Public key RPB format --> no worries about this
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in pub.pem -outform RPB -out pub.rpb

// ECDSA
// Private key --> already have this
openssl ecparam -genkey -out ecdsa_priv.pem -name prime256v1

// Public key --> NEED THIS <--
openssl ec -in ecdsa_priv.pem -pubout -out ecdsa_pub.pem

// Public key DER format --> NEED THIS <--
openssl ec -pubin -inform PEM -in ecdsa_pub.pem -outform DER -out ecdsa_pub.der
```

Comment: ECDSA is a way to perform DSA using Elliptic Curves; it is not a format and it is not compatible with RSA, obviously. DER is the Distinguished Encoding Rules; it is a way to encode ASN.1 defined data structures, but it is **not** specific to any format. And I tried to look up RPB and came up with nothing.

Comment: I did not vote down, but i could imagine that people vote it down because of the misunderstanding of the formats. Although annoying,  remember that the votes are not personal. I've asked the same question when I was a new user but please understand that the downvoyers usually  not following the question.

Comment: Yea, not personal at all :-), just curious, so will try not to make the same mistakes.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> // Public key PEM --> already have this
> openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubin -in pub.pem -text -noout

Not really. Java `PublicKey.getEncoded()` -- or in Kotlin just `.encoded` -- is the X.509-SPKI *format* publickey, which is the same format `openssl` uses. When you encode to base64 AND add linebreaks every 64 AND add a line `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` before and a line `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` after, THEN it is the same as OpenSSL PEM, which is also standard; see [RFC7468 section 2 and 13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2). Depending on how you will use this file or data, you may get away without the linebreaks in the base64; not all programs require that. But most programs that use PEM do enforce the dash-BEGIN and dash-END lines.

> // Public key DER format --> NEED THIS <--
> openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in pub.pem -outform DER -out pub.der

This is trivial. Just skip the base64 encoding; the return from `PublicKey.getEncoded()` is exactly this format already (as `byte[]`).

> // Public key RPB format --> no worries about this
> openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in pub.pem -outform RPB -out pub.rpb

What is this openssl that you are using? Where/how did you get it? No 'real' OpenSSL -- that is, from the OpenSSL project at [www.openssl.org](http://www.openssl.org) -- has such an option for `-outform`. I don't think LibreSSL does either, though I don't track it nearly as closely.

> // ECDSA
> // Private key --> already have this
> openssl ecparam -genkey -out ecdsa_priv.pem -name prime256v1
> // Public key --> NEED THIS <--
> openssl ec -in ecdsa_priv.pem -pubout -out ecdsa_pub.pem
> // Public key DER format --> NEED THIS <--
> openssl ec -pubin -inform PEM -in ecdsa_pub.pem -outform DER -out ecdsa_pub.der

These were generated from an EC key (or really keypair), NOT an RSA key. Note that although you used the filename ecdsa, the same keys are actually used for ECDSA and ECDH and possibly EQMQV; accordingly in Java you use `KeyPairGenerator|KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")` but `Signature.getInstance("ECDSA")` and `KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH")`.

If you have one of those key objects, i.e. one with interface `ECPrivateKey` not `RSAPrivateCrtKey`, and BouncyCastle, which your post suggests but doesn't actually state, you can tweak the method I recently wrote in [Extract public key from PrivateKeyInfo with Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413281/extract-public-key-from-privatekeyinfo-with-bouncy-castle):

```
    // import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo and org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1BitString
    PrivateKeyInfo privinfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance( ecprivkeyobject.getEncoded() );
    ASN1BitString wrappt = org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.ECPrivateKey.getInstance(privinfo.getPrivateKey().getOctets()).getPublicKey();
    // use full name to avoid conflict with 'standard' java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey
    byte[] spki = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(privinfo.getPrivateKeyAlgorithm(), wrappt).getEncoded() ));
```

That `byte[] spki` IS the openssl DER format for EC, and similar to RSA if you base64-encode, add linebreaks, and add BEGIN/END lines, that is the openssl (and standard = RFC7468) PEM format.

Added: also, your current method for RSA is unnecessarily roundabout. You don't need to create one `PrivateKey` for RSA, take its encoding, run that encoding through a `KeyFactory` with `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` to produce a second `PrivateKey` that you cast to `RSAPrivateCrtKey`; instead you can just cast the original `PrivateKey` and use that to get the `modulus` and `publicExponent` to put in `RSAPublicKeySpec`. This case was also in the previous Q I linked.